# Why does a question mark appears in the output of my function and how can I avoid it?

Tags: c

I've read some posts about the question mark but it didn't work.
Here's the code for the function : (i want to create one like "strcpy")

```
char *stringcopy(char *word1, char *word2)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; word2[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        word1[i] = word2[i];
    }
    return word1;


}
```

if I call the function for example like this : `printf("%s", stringcopy(word1, "hello"));`
it gives me this : "hello?"

Comment: You're not actually copying the null character into word1, you're just stopping at it so the question mark is the junk after the end of word1

Comment: So, inserting `word1[i] = '\0';` after the end of the for-loop should fix the issue. Alternatively, use a `do-while` loop.

Comment: `printf` will print the characters until it encounters the null char. if the memory that word points contains any values other than 0 aka null char, it will be printed as well. That's why you must add null termination char or simply a 0 to the end of word1, typically you can put it to the end of the for loop (outside of it), to the last index.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *stringcopy(char *word1, char *word2)
{
    int i = 0;
    while( word2[i] != '\0')
    {
        word1[i] = word2[i];
        i++;
    }

    word1[i]='\0';
    return word1;


}
```

You can add NULL characters after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop terminates when `word2[i] == '\0'` and the body of the loop is not executed `word1` contains not terminated string. You can terminate it by writing `'\0'` after the loop or simply modifying the loop itself. You can also can use another types of loop:

```
char *stringcopy(char *word1, char *word2)
{
    size_t i = 0;

    for (i = 0; (word1[i] = word2[i]) != '\0'; i++);
    return word1;
}

char *stringcopy1(char *word1, char *word2)
{
    size_t i = 0;
    for (i = 0; word2[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        word1[i] = word2[i];
    }
    word1[i] = '\0';
    return word1;
}

char *stringcopy2(char *word1, const char *word2)
{
    char *wrk = word1;

    while((*wrk++ = *word2++) != '\0');
    return word1;
}

char *stringcopy3(char *word1, const char *word2)
{
    char *wrk = word1;

    do
    {
        *wrk++ = *word2;
    }
    while(*word2++ != '\0');
    return word1;
}
```

BTW the index variable should have `size_t` type.